# add legend for some of the lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

**I want to add legend to illustrate different value of a, there are 6 lines in the picture, however the two have the same color have the same value of a.I want to add a legend has only three lines in it, indicating $a=1$, $a=2$, $a=3$ for different color.**

Note this code has a loop, so I don't know how to deal with it.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(a,x):
    return a*x
def g(a,x):
    return 5*a*x

const=[1,2,3]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
colors=['r','b','g']
xArray=np.linspace(0,2,20)
for i in const:
    ax.plot(xArray,f(i,xArray),color=colors[i-1])
    ax.plot(xArray,g(i,xArray),color=colors[i-1],ls='--')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are only included when [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html) is called and a string is provided as an argument for the label variable (e.g. label='???').

For example this adds (only) three lines to the legend:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(a,x):
    return a*x
def g(a,x):
    return 5*a*x

const=[1,2,3]

fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
colors=['r','b','g']
labels = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
xArray=np.linspace(0,2,20)
for i in const:
    ax.plot(xArray,f(i,xArray), color=colors[i-1], 
            label=labels[i-1])
    ax.plot(xArray,g(i,xArray), color=colors[i-1],ls='--')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```